# Set background from UIAlertView option xcode

Tags: ios

Im trying to do an app with 4 ImageViews and 4 UIButtons. When one of the UIButtons are pressed a UIAlertView should appear with 3 options. One named "Picture" should open the photo library so the user can change the ImageView picture. I have wrote a code for this but it wont work. Do anyone have any suggestions on how to make it work?
Thanks in advance!

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
NSString *buttonOne = changeButtonOne;  //the UIButtons
NSString *buttonTwo = changeButtonTwo;
NSString *buttonThree = changeButtonThree;
NSString *buttonFour = changeButtonFour;


if([buttonOne isEqualToString:@"buttonOne"])
{
      if([title isEqualToString:@"Done"])
    {
        NSLog(@"You pressed done");
    }
      else if([title isEqualToString:@"Phone number"])
    {
        NSLog(@"You pressed Phone number");
    }
      else if([title isEqualToString:@"Picture"])
    {
        imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];   //I think its this part which are wrong
        [imagePickerController setDelegate:self];
        [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
else if([buttonTwo isEqualToString:@"buttonTwo"])
{
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Done"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Yoy pressed done");
    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"Phone number"])
    {
        NSLog(@"You pressed Phone number");
    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"Picture"])
    {
        imagePickerController2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];  //I think its the part thats wrong.
        [imagePickerController2 setDelegate:self];
        [imagePickerController2 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        [self presentViewController:imagePickerController2 animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

}
else if([buttonThree isEqualToString:@"buttonThree"])
    {
        if([title isEqualToString:@"Done"])
        {
            NSLog(@"You pressed done");
        }
        else if([title isEqualToString:@"Phone number"])
        {
            NSLog(@"You pressed Phone number");
        }
        else if([title isEqualToString:@"Picture"])
        {
            imagePickerController3 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];   //i think this is the wrong part
            [imagePickerController3 setDelegate:self];
            [imagePickerController3 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
            [self presentViewController:imagePickerController3 animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }

    else if([buttonFour isEqualToString:@"buttonFour"])
    {
        if([title isEqualToString:@"Done"])
        {
            NSLog(@"You pressed done");
        }
        else if([title isEqualToString:@"Phone number"])
        {
            NSLog(@"You pressed Phone number");
        }
        else if([title isEqualToString:@"Picture"])
        {
            imagePickerController4 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];    //this is probably the wrong part
            [imagePickerController4 setDelegate:self];
            [imagePickerController4 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
            [self presentViewController:imagePickerController4 animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }




}

@end
```

Comment: You wrote some code, so can you post that so we can see if what you did is wrong?

Comment: @wmichaelsen The whole file is unnecessary, and few people will want to sift through all of that to find the one line you possibly made a mistake on.  Try only pasting selected lines relating to the specific problem you are having

Comment: What exactly is it about your code that isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `tag` property of UIAlertView to differentiate between the alerts and the `buttonIndex` (not the button title) to know which button was pressed.
So don't use isEqualToString at all in the alert view delegate method. You want this to work with different languages.

In the button action, before you show the alert:

```
alertView.tag = 1; // 1 = button1, 2 = button2 etc.
```

Alert view delegate:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag == 1) { //button1
        if (buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
            // handle cancel button
        }        
        if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex) {
            // handle action 1
        }
        if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex+1) {
            // handle action 2
        }
    }
    if (alertView.tag == 2) { //button2
        if (buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
            // handle cancel button
        }        
        if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex) {
            // handle action 3
        }
        if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex+1) {
            // handle action 4
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but could you give an example of how it can be written?

Comment: It says that "firstOtherButtonIndex" is use of undeclared identifier?

Comment: sorry, I fixed that in my answer

Comment: thanks but the first part"alertView.tag = 1", it wants me to replace "alerView" with "UIAlertView" and if I do that it doesnt work either?

Comment: `alertView` is your UIAlertView instance. Just rename the variable to match it with your code.

Comment: it doesnt work:( when I click the first button I get to the main.m file and the log pops up